# What vehicles are cross compatable?

Tags: repair, part-identification, replace

When buying 2 salvaged vehicles, one totaled in the front and the other in the rear, to make 1 whole car where do I go to check the capability of 2 different years cars? What vehicles have the most match across the year models? I understand that some years have no other match, but I am looking for the most abundant match.

Bonus question and example My car is a 2001 Toyota Camry how far out side of this year model to use the parts that all match?

Comment: This question is extremely broad. What kind of a time frame are you talking about? As written, you're suggesting information on all vehicles ever made. That's literally tens of thousands of different makes/models. I'm not sure this question is a very good question for the site, even if you trim down what you're talking about.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Make be the question should read... what is the most vehicle including cross capability?

Comment: I don't think there's any way for this question to be answerable. There are just too many makes and models, and too many variations in how vehicles are assembled. How would you even verify that the answer is correct?

Comment: The most vehicle including cross capability is a bicycle. Most parts are interchangeable.

Comment: Doing this in the UK is almost certainly illegal, if you intend to drive the repaired vehicle on public roads. For example it can not be registered, and would fail the annual MOT safety test simply because the VIN numbers on the vehicle didn't match the registration, unless it was put through an "approval test" and given a special (so called  Q) registration number. Of course it *is* possible to go through this process (e.g. to legally operate a "stretch limo") but the majority of such "cut and shut" vehicles are not legal, and probably not safe to drive either.

Comment: I am not sure how "International" the info is, but in the US the "Hollander Interchange Manual" was the holy grail for parts compatibility. It is now available on line. At one time prior to the internet, used versions were highly coveted and sold for hundreds of dollars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (and only) way to answer is to look at your specific vehicle. This is an XV20 model, made from 1996 to 2001. It was also known as the Daihatsu Altis, Toyota Vienta and Toyota Camry Gracia - but there's no shortage of Camrys in the junk yards if you're looking for parts. Be aware that a car that old isn't worth much - where is the benefit in buying two broken ones to make one that works? For the same price, you'll probably find a decent one.

Comment: Cosmetically no change over on engine and such.

Comment: @Muze Not to bait the trolls, but many of your "sentences" lack a verb.